# map subarray with new values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, `array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`.

I need a new array with the value `[[1,2,3], [8,10,12]]`

I tried `array[1].map((el) => el*2)`, but it's not return the array which I want.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code looks fine but `map` returns a copy of the array, it's not in place. Did you reassign it to `array[1]`? Are you trying to generalize this pattern or just apply the operation to `array[1]`? If the former, what should a longer array map to?

Comment: Thank you bro, I forgot reassigning it to new array, I`ve solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

You might use a nested map, multiply by the index of the outer map you're on (plus one).

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
const result = arr.map((subarr, i) =>
  subarr.map(val => val * (i + 1))
);
console.log(result);
```